# There are some details lost in my final render

Tags: modeling, objects, blender-internal-render-engine

I am at the very end of the doughnut tutorial and trying to render my image, but I am running into a problem. There are parts in my icing, towards the camera, that are awkwardly cut off.

But when I press shift+z, the render looks fine. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Final Render

[image]

Shift+Z

[doughnut tutorial part 9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25N775uHb_4)

Comment: Most likely you have a Subdivision Surface modifier with different settings for the level of subdivision for Preview and Render. When in Preview it’s looking OK but when you render the different amount of subdiv results in the surface being below the doughnut.

Comment: I see. I looked at the modifier settings for the icing and the doughnut itself when it was rendered, and it looks the same as in preview mode. Is there something that I am not looking at?

Comment: Do you have a Subdivision Surface modifier? If so, you should see separate 'Subdivisions' settings for 'View' and 'Render'. Are those set to different values (they default to '1' and '2' respectively). If they are set to different values then it will result in different final mesh when in Preview mode (where it will use the 'View' number of subdivisions) or Render mode (where it will use the 'Render' number of subdivisions).